# Objects from same array using for loop with j = i + 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, collision

I have a loop to check collision between objects in my game, all the objects are collected in the same Array. I use a code like this to match every object with eachother:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < objs.length; j++) {
        collision(objs[i], objs[j]);
    }
}
```

Now this does not seem to actually perform all collisions with eachother, I've noticed that it skips some too..

Then I came up with this solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < objs.length; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            collision(objs[i], objs[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution seem to not have any problems, but I wonder if there is any kinda way to not have to use the `if (j != i)` statement, or is there maybe a totally different solution?

Comment: Why I+1? Shouldnt you start j at 1? Weird things going on here

Comment: I used j = i + 1 as I copied it from another game..

Comment: When i is at 1 j will also be 1 and that will be an error

Comment: Your first code snippet is correct. Your second snippet will check every pair twice.

Comment: @GIJoe `i+1` is correct. Starting `j` and `1` would be wrong.

Comment: @meagar: No, starting j at 1 and i at 0 would be correct

Comment: Soo, who's correct eh..?

Comment: He is iterating through each object in the array, starting at 0 and seeing if the next one collides. It's not efficient but it works.

Comment: @Murplyx meagar is correct. Your first code is fine. Why do you think it does not perform all collisions?

Comment: because it fails in my game

Comment: @Murplyx That doesn't mean anything to us. Does the order of arguments in `collision` matter?

Comment: @Murplyx Cool project. However we're not going to go through 2k lines of code. You've asked the question and assuming that the order of arguments in `collision` does not matter then the first piece of code you've shown us is fine.

Comment: Off-topic: consider caching `objs.length` in a variable to improve performance, specially if `objs` is a huge array.

Comment: Congrats on being 13 and programming your own game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Soo, who's correct eh..?

It depends on the definition of *collision* in your game.

If `collision` is a [symmetric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric#Symmetric_functions) (i.e. A collides with B if, and only if, B collides with A), then use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < objs.length; j++) {
        collision(objs[i], objs[j]);
    }
}
```

because there's no need to check (B,A) if you checked (A,B) before.

But if it is possible to make A collide with B without making B collide with A, or vice versa, then you must check all possible different pairs, so use

```
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < objs.length; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            collision(objs[i], objs[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soo, who's correct eh..?

It depends on the definition of collision in your game.

If collision is a symmetric function (i.e. A collides with B if, and only if, B collides with A), then use:

for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < objs.length; j++) {
        collision(objs[i], objs[j]);
    }
}
because there's no need to check (B,A) if you checked (A,B) before.

But if it is possible to make A collide with B without making B collide with A, or vice versa, then you must check all possible different pairs, so use

for (var i = 0; i < objs.length..... this I think...

Comment: @Murplyx I like it! But once zombies hit you, you die too fast :S

Comment: @Oriol: and he is only 13!